# Hive- Extract timestamp and date in defined format

Tags: hive

I have column value in my HIVE table in String format like 20160921091213 i.e. YYYYMMDDHHMMDD. In target I have two columns one timestamp and other date column. I want to extract the same in the format for timestamp "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS" and for date in the format "YYYY-MM-DD".

What can be the possible SQL for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert to unix timestamp format and then convert back to string.

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20160921091213', 'yyyyMMddHHmmss'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

Result: `2016-09-21 21:12:13`